# Convert binary string to string in javascript

Tags: javascript, tostring

I have a Binary string and I want to convert it into a string format.
here is the function,

```
let stringConversion = (n) => {
  let convertToString = n.toString();
  console.log(convertToString);
};

stringConversion(00000000000000000000000000001011);
```

The output I want is "00000000000000000000000000001011" but it is giving me "521"

Comment: you handover a **number** with leading zero. this value is read in octal if possible.

Comment: `00000000000000000000000000001011` is not going to be interpreted as a binary number. That would be `0b1011`. But either way, you won't be able to always get back the same representation that was used in the source code. At *runtime* there is no difference between `0b000001011` and `0b1011`. Maybe provide more information about what you are trying to achieve here and why.

Comment: Where would this `000000000000001011` come from? If it's from a user input, it's a string anyway. If it's from a database, it will never be stored as such, with those leading zeroes. If it's the result of a computation, it won't have those leading zeroes either. What kind of process leads to such a number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JS a number token that starts with a `0` and does not contain a `9` is read in octal base. So the interpreter convert your number into a decal base, and you obtain a different number: `01011 => (1011)8 = (521)10`.

If the token stats with `0b` it is read as binary string also, so you could just append it to your number: `0b1011 => (1011)2 = (11)10`.

Now if you want to convert a bit string, well, actually it should be literally a string. You should do something like `stringConversion('00000000000000000000000000001011');`

I wrote some code that helps you to find the right way to encode/decode a binary string into a **UNSIGNED** (theoretically) infinite number. If you want to keep sign, you should provide some more informations to the binary string, like for example a fixed length or pretend that the first bit is the sign.

```js
function binary2number(bitStr) {
  // initialize the result to 0
  let result = 0;

  for (let bit of bitStr) {
    // shift the current result one bit to the left
    result <<= 1;
    // adding the current bit
    result += !!parseInt(bit);
  }

  return result;
};

function number2binary(num, minBitLength=0) {
  // converting the number to a string in base 2
  let result = num.toString(2)
  
  // concatenate the missing '0' up to minBitLength
  while (result.length < minBitLength) {
    result = '0' + result;
  }
  return result;
}

console.log('00000000000000000000000000001011 (in 8 base) is interpreted as' ,
   00000000000000000000000000001011, '(in 10 base)');

console.log('00000000000000000000000000001011 =>',
   binary2number('00000000000000000000000000001011'));

console.log('11 =>', number2binary(11, 32), '(32 bits = unsigned int commonly)');

console.log('11 =>', number2binary(11), '(for short)');
```

Now, this is the conventional way to represent a binary integer, but if your bit string should represent something different, a float for example, the code would drastically change. You could also define your own way to parse that string. There are also many underlying assumptions, which I will not dig into (like endian, and other finite memory representation stuffs).